# Display Facebook Status Publicly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

There a couple posts on this topic non of them really talk about posting your facebook status publicly.  I'm looking to post a facebook status publicly just like you can with a twitter update.  Does anyone have a fully working code example of this?

*Note: I am not looking for a plugin for something like wordpress.  I am looking for a homegrown solution based on the API.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mini-feed of your status that you can use.  Here is an example for [showing your facebook status on a wordpress blog](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/how-to-display-facebook-statuses-on-wordpress-blog/).

There is an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383777/php-function-to-get-facebook-status) already going on about this.  It looks like PEAR's [Services_Facebook](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Facebook) might help you out.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to query upon in it in something other than wordpress.

Comment: Well you can still use the feed URL and do something else with the XML.