# Facebook Status on website

Tags: php, facebook

[PHP function to get Facebook status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383777/php-function-to-get-facebook-status)

I've got to step 5 but im stuck.

How can I output these results in html format for say 10 status messages?

Thanks,
David

Comment: can you post the status message array you have (piped down to 2 messages) and your expected output??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```php
echo $response['data'][0]['message']
```

or

```php
var_dump($response['data'][0]['message'])
```

?