# get latest status update from facebook page

Tags: php, facebook

How do i grab the latest status update from a facebook page in php? Not a users profile but a page (that you can like)? The documentation is a nightmare. Having trouble finding an answer to this!

Comment: Ok yes. perhaps not perfectly worded ;) You don't have any ideas though?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383777/php-function-to-get-facebook-status

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pages are just the same as profiles in terms of accessing them though the graph.  To get the wall posts from a page you use the url `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed`.

Adding a limit parameter will return only the most recent: `https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?limit=1`.

Here's a quick and dirty example of how this would work in PHP:

```
try {
    $feed = $facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/feed?limit=1');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes thanks, I've jst found this in the docs...but now my problem is I don't know the id of my page....I didn't create it.

Comment: You can use the name of the page as it appears in the URL, i.e. `https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed`, but this will require a valid access token. See the examples at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: @shanethehat Can you please show me how to only get the status of the page?  Would you like me to post another thread?

Comment: Seriously, looked everywhere. This is the least convoluted answer. I'd +1000 it if I could.