# Facebook Latest Status Updates

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to get the latest facebook status updates using PHP without getting logged in Facebook. I have seen the query parameter 'scope:offline_access'. But in somewhere on net I have seen that facebook is depreciating this feature. So what should I do now? Also most of the codes that I found here doesn't seem to work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Facebook Latest Status Updates but i find one question on stackoverflow check out that link
[PHP function to get Facebook status?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383777/718224)
may this help you.

Answer (score 0):

applications which already get this permission is working perfectly but not new apps so this is not possible you need new access token now everytime

Comment: Hi Mohit, Thanks for you quick response. Being a newbie I want to know how to get the access token after the page get redirected along with the access token. Used $_GET to get the access token from the returned url but with no luck. I just want the access token to be stored in a variable like ( $token = $_GET['access_token']). Is that possible?

Comment: i'm not sure about that variable but var_dump($_REQUEST) you can see variable